# options does not turn green

Tags: jquery

In my jsfiddle, what happens is the user clicks on the "Open Grid" link and select an option. The option value is then displayed in the textbox. Now if you open the grid again you would see the option you have chosen turns green. Now this works for options "3" to "21". But for options "22", "23", "24" all the way to the "Yes or No" options if you select them, the value is shown in the textbox but the option does not turn green when you open up the grid.

Why is this.

The code is in a jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cKm/34/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think it happens because you have duplicate `id` property. That's only for numbers.

Second, if you want to turn buttons with text 'Yes or No' and 'True or False' you should change the behavior of this peace of code:

`$("#btn" + value).addClass("gridBtnsOn");`

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cKm/37/).

Comment: Perhaps changing `value` to `value.replace(/\s/g, '');` fit your needs. In this case, all whitespace symbols will be removed from string so you can place text "True or False" on the button and use "TrueorFalse" as an part of id property.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to see the code change but I can't see it, think I need to go to specsavers lol :). By the way if you just add a space in the value from TrueorFalse to True or False and same from YesorNo, then it sorts it out

Comment: Oh, I've changed the id from btn15... to btn22 and value attribute from "True or False" to "TrueorFalse". [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cKm/39/) is the fiddle that uses value.replace(/\s/g, ''); in javascript that I described above. Also, in this fiddle I brought back value="True or False".

Comment: Oh, ok so I still had to include the value.replace() even though I change the value TrueorFalse to True or False and same for Yes or No. Thanks for your help. It has worked :)

Comment: Of course, you have 2 options: 1. use value.replace in javascript and feel free to put spaces in value attribute in html or 2. use just value in js and not to use spaces in value attribute in html. You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the IDs on these five items:

```
<input class="gridBtns" name="btn22Name"  id="btn15"     type="button"  value="22"  />
<input class="gridBtns" name="btn23Name"  id="btn16"     type="button"  value="23"  />
<input class="gridBtns" name="btn24Name"  id="btn17"     type="button"  value="24"  />
<input class="gridBtns" name="btn25Name"  id="btn18"     type="button"  value="25"  />
<input class="gridBtns" name="btn26Name"  id="btn19"     type="button"  value="26"  />
```

Notice that they are set to the wrong numbers and these IDs have already been defined earlier.

Comment: Oh my god, what a waste of a question, I can't believe I have done that mistake, thats the price when you copy lines of code to create the buttons quickly, thank you :)

Comment: I have updated the 5 items but if I select True or False option or Yes or No option, it does not turn those options green, do you know why?